# Why does Troi not tell people about Lutan's desire for Tasha?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Having just watched the episode "Code of Honor" from *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, how come upon meeting Lutan, Troi sensed his avarice, ambition and a strong desire for Tasha, but said nothing? She even told the others later that she'd sensed it, and no one pulls her up on it!

Comment: In the future can you try and provide more descriptive titles that describe what it is you're actually asking. Also Star Trek questions should always have the `[star-trek]` tag.

Comment: Perhaps it would be considered a violation of personal privacy? Though I'm not sure the show ever really goes into the discussion of Betazoid/empath ethics - most shown seem fine revealing the private thoughts/feelings of others.

Comment: "TROI: Some sexual attraction from all the males. Lieutenant Yar is physically very attractive. But with Lutan I felt something else. Something more like avarice or ambition." - she does say something, prior to Lutan announcing her as First One

Comment: Pretty sure this episode is just someone's crazy holonovel adventure being played out.

Comment: The MissionLog Podcast has fascinating observations about the episode and how it was, in the eyes of many, a terrible example of racism and colonialism, etc..but that the script, without the visual or audio isn't that way at all - it was all about the casting and direction that made it so stereotyped. Well worth a listen if you have a hate / hate relationship with the episode.

Answer (score 2):

You're conflating two separate things that she sensed; Lutan's strong and extremely obvious attraction for Tasha Yar (which pretty much *everyone* noticed, regardless of their empathic ability) and Lutan's personal desire for power and influence.

Frankly, the first wasn't worth mentioning. Troi herself notes that Yar is a very good-looking woman and that strong feelings of lust to her were coming from *all* the men present.

> **TROI:** *...Some sexual attraction from **all the males**. Lieutenant Yar is physically very attractive.*

and while she might have mentioned that Lutan was an

> avaricious and ambitious

man, giving that information to Picard would be like telling the Captain a Romulan visitor is "sneaky" or that a Vulcan is "cold", it's nothing he doesn't already know or couldn't guess on his own.